# Multibodyplant single object port

Tags: drake

I want to update the position of *one* object in my multibodyplant using a PID controller. I need a single update port, but iirc get_state_output_port returns the output port for all states. How should I do this?

Also, what is the state convention? In the docs, it says get_state_output_port returns [q, v]. But what *is* q for a RigidBody? Is it [position, quaternion] or [quaternion, position]? How are supposed to know this from the docs?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the state for a single *model_instance* using the [overloaded version](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_multibody_plant.html#a00693ff4108f9634a03e5799c9306428) of the `get_state_output_port()` method.  There is a comparable overload for `get_actuation_input_port()`.

Re: the order of q, the short answer is e.g.

```
('body1_qw', 'body1_qx', 'body1_qy', 'body1_qz', 'body1_x',
 'body1_y', 'body1_z', 'body2_qw', 'body2_qx', 'body2_qy',
 'body2_qz', 'body2_x', 'body2_y', 'body2_z')
```

We have an issue discussing introspection for `MultibodyPlant` [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/10736) which gives some additional context.  And I have helper methods [here](https://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation/blob/396fe7c40b5881a58bbb5b8f083b70c1c11bd94f/manipulation/utils.py#L148) that I will push to Drake. I've just started drafting a PR for that port now and will try to land it soon.

Comment: Is the quaternion supposed to be normalized? It seems like it isn't.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems like get_state_output_port returns unnormalized quaternion, but I don't see any convenience function in Pydrake to convert unnormalized quaternion to the normalized quaternion (there is a ClosestQuaternion in C++ drake)

Comment: The initial conditions should have the normalized quaternion.  We do not explicitly normalize it inside the dynamics, but I would expect it to be close to normalized.  

Re: the missing bindings.  That is easily fixed: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/19208